# DNS hierarchy with bind

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, internet

I'm doing a project from class in which I want to simulate a dns hierarchy that works as the global internet dns hierarchy. The structure is like this:

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Tnh.jpg)

So all the requests will be sent to the root server that will return the ip of the edu server and that one will return the ip of kevin or bech server depending on the request.

I configured all the servers manually with bind like this:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     kevin.edu. root.kevin.edu. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

        IN      NS      dns.kevin.edu.

www     IN      A       1.1.1.7
kgs     IN      A       1.1.1.8
dns     IN      A       1.1.1.5
```

My problem now is that I want to resolve this recursively, the host only will know the ip of the root dns server and when he wants to know the ip of www.kevin.edu first will ask the edu ip to the root, then the kevin.edu to the edu and finally the www.kevin.edu to the kevin.

Any idea of how can I make that?

Edit:

Config file of the root dns server:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     . root.kevin.edu. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

        IN      NS      dns.

edu     IN      A       1.1.1.4
dns     IN      A       1.1.1.3
```

Comment: That's the problem of the resolver (the DNS client) which can sometimes be the DNS server provided by an ISP. It's its job to start asking from the root (`.`) and go down the hierarchy (to `kevin.edu`) if necessarily. All you need to do is setup correctly the zones of those servers.

Comment: Is there any special configuration that I need to set to make this? I can access to all the servers if I connect directly to the zone that contains them so I can't find any problem in the configuration files

Comment: No, but you might want to either setup a resolving DNS server or use a recursive client, perhaps **dig** with `+trace`.

Comment: Doing that I get an error saying dig:(couldn't get address for 'dns': failure). I'm adding the root config file to the question.

Comment: When performing a lookup, if there isn't already data cached, a resolver server cannot know what is delegated and what isn't. If it has been tasked with looking up `www.kevin.edu` this is the name that it will use in its queries, starting already with the query sent to the root servers. (The query does not change, it is only directed at different servers as the resolver server follows the chain of delegations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root zone, as shown in the question, does not contain any delegation information for `edu`, only an `A` record. By this definition `edu` is not a zone of its own but just a name that is part of the root zone.

To match your description of what you want, the `edu` `A` record should not be in the root zone, instead there should be delegatory `NS` records + glue `A`/`AAAA` records, so that it's possible to follow the delegation.

For example something like this:

```
edu.    IN  NS  ns.edu.    ; delegation
ns.edu. IN  A   1.1.1.4    ; glue
```

Matching records should exist in the authoritative zones (the `edu` zone in this case) as well.

After ensuring that there is actually delegation in place between all of your different zones it should be pretty straightforward to get a resolver server to work with your custom DNS tree.
It should just be a matter of providing root hints (`NS` + glue `A`/`AAAA` records) for your custom root zone and possibly disabling/overriding any dnssec settings that relate to how the real root zone is signed.